# What is this item? Unknown device in old laundry closet in newer construction house

Tags: plumbing, shower, laundry

I am planning on turning the space where an old laundry closet used to be into a shower area as part of a more extensive renovation (house was built in 2006). As part of the planning and design part of this process I came upon this black thing sticking out of the wall, which I have no idea what it is? My best guess is it is an old sealed off vent pipe? I figured I would ask here (pic included) to see what it might be before I start tearing up the place. Additionally, if there are any tips on how it could be removed or hidden behind the wall (if possible/permitted by code) that would be appreciated.

For context, the water tray for the old washer is on the bottom. Cold and hot water connections (not seen in pic) are further up on the wall to the right of the unknown device.

Thanks!

[image: sample pic]

Comment: looks like cleanout access to an existing sewer pipe .... what is in the room above this area?

Comment: Right above is the attic to the roof. On the other side of this wall is a bathroom sink fwiw.

Comment: there you go, now you know what it's for

Comment: Have you accounted for the washing machine drain?

Comment: Yes, that is part of the small panel with the hot/cold hookups (not pictured).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like a drain clean-out. If your drain pipes clog deep in the system, the cap can be removed to get a fairly straight shot down to the common sewer for a roto-rooter-type machine.

You should probably find a new location to add one in  its place.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the gas line, and the dryer vent. Way too small to be a clean out.

Comment: I don't think its gas as this house is all electric and its not a dryer vent (I removed where the old one was :) ).